# Adding attributes to intersected polygons from corresponding columns R

Tags: r, polygon, fields-attributes, intersect, for-loop

In short, I have a set of 10 polygons in `Pol_large`, that I want to split to individual polygons by intersecting (intersecting areas become new polygons, and old ones get cropped). In result, I am obtaining 14 individual polygons in `poly_output`.

I have an issue in my final loop that I am unable to solve. What I want to achieve is to merge attribute information into the intersected polygons from the corresponding parent polygons into new columns with the `_Merged` suffix. Those attributes would be then listed by commas (here we have max two parent polygons but in my real example it can be more than that. I tried to execute it with a loop but there is something wrong with how I set the identifiers.
EDIT: I discovered the issue. In my example when a small polygon was entirely within the other one, there was no corresponding "parent" polygon. Thus, I need to tell the loop what to do in that case.

```
Error in identifiers[z] <- which(sf_obj$orig_polys_ids == identifiers_r[z]) : 
  replacement has length zero
```

Function `poly_f` is working as it should.

This tiny bug is driving me crazy - in my large example some of the rows are executed fine, the rest fails. Here is the full code:

```
library(sp)
library(sf)

create_poly <- function(coordin,id_number){
  coordinates = matrix(c(coordin[1], coordin[3],
                         coordin[1], coordin[4],
                         coordin[2], coordin[4],
                         coordin[2], coordin[3],
                         coordin[1], coordin[3]), 
                       ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  P_1 = Polygon(coordinates)
  Ps_1 = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(P_1), ID = id_number)), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
  ID_1 <- sapply(slot(Ps_1, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID"))
  df <- data.frame(rep(0, length(ID_1)), row.names=ID_1)
  Ps1_df <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Ps_1, df)
  Ps1_df
}

# Create shapefile with polygon boundaries of interest:
Pol_1 <- create_poly(c(80,100,25,40),1) #
Pol_2 <- create_poly(c(145,170,40,60),1)
Pol_3 <- create_poly(c(100,120,55,65),1)
Pol_4 <- create_poly(c(90,120,35,50),1) 
Pol_5 <- create_poly(c(130,150,30,50),1) 
Pol_6 <- create_poly(c(80,105,58,62),1)
Pol_7 <- create_poly(c(120,150,10,20),1)
Pol_8 <- create_poly(c(120,150,10,20),1) 
Pol_9 <- create_poly(c(75,95,15,30),1)
Pol_10 <- create_poly(c(90,110,10,20),1)

# Join the polygons into one layer:
Pol_large <- do.call(rbind, list(Pol_1, Pol_2, Pol_3, Pol_4, Pol_5, 
                                 Pol_6, Pol_7, Pol_8, Pol_9, Pol_10))
plot(Pol_large, axes = TRUE) # plot

# Add attributes
Pol_large@data$Name <- c("A","F","D","G","E","B","I","H","34","2")
Pol_large@data$Category <- c("mono","mono","poly","mono","poly","poly","poly",
                             "mono","mono","poly")
Pol_large@data$Subcategor <- c("1","0","1","0","1","0","1","1","0","1")
Pol_large@data$Colour <- c("blue","red","yellow","green","black","brown",
                               "blue","orange","red","black")
# Convert from sp to sf object
Pol_large <- st_as_sf(Pol_large)

# Now pull important attributes to the intersected polygons:
attributes <- c("Name","Category","Subcategor")
attributes_Merged <- c("Name_Merged","Category_Merged","Subcategor_Merged")

# Rows to keep in the large polygon based on names (residual from large example)
allowed_names <- c("A","F","D","G","E","B","I","H","34","2")

# Function creating new polygons from intersected areas
poly_f <- function(poly_c, attrib){
  poly_c <- subset(poly_c, poly_c$Name %in% attrib)
  poly_c$orig_poly_id <- seq(1,nrow(poly_c),1)
  poly_c_inters <- st_intersection(poly_c)
  for (i in 1:nrow(poly_c_inters)){
    poly_c_inters$orig_polys_ids[i] <- paste(as.vector(poly_c_inters$origins[[i]]), collapse=', ')
  }
  return(poly_c_inters)
}

poly_output <- poly_f(Pol_large, allowed_names)

sf_obj <- poly_output
attr_vector <- attributes_Merged

# Create new columns from the attribute vector
for(i in 1:length(attr_vector)){
  sf_obj[,attr_vector[i]] <- NA
}

# Add attributes to the new cols from the corresponding parent rows 
# and list by commas
for (i in 1:nrow(sf_obj)){
  if(sf_obj$n.overlaps[i]>1){
    identifiers_r <- as.vector(sf_obj$origins[[i]])
    identifiers <- vector(length = length(identifiers_r))
    for (z in 1:length(identifiers_r)){
      identifiers[z] <- which(sf_obj$orig_polys_ids == identifiers_r[z])
    }
    for (j in 1:length(sf_obj$origins[[i]])){
      sf_obj$Name_Merged[i] <- paste0(sf_obj$Name_Merged[i],",",sf_obj$Name[identifiers[j]])
      sf_obj$Category_Merged[i] <- paste0(sf_obj$Category_Merged[i],",",sf_obj$Category[identifiers[j]])
      sf_obj$Subcategor_Merged[i] <- paste0(sf_obj$Subcategor_Merged[i],",",sf_obj$Subcategor[identifiers[j]])
    }
  }else{
    identifiers <- as.vector(sf_obj$origins[[i]])
    sf_obj$Name_Merged[i] <- sf_obj$Name[i]
    sf_obj$Category_Merged[i] <- sf_obj$Category[i]
    sf_obj$Subcategor_Merged[i] <- sf_obj$Subcategor[i]
  }
}
```